# How do I restrict tag formats permitted in a GitHub repo?

Tags: github

I want to ensure that tags pushed to my GitHub repo obey the [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) format.  How can I achieve this?  I have found the documentation for protected branches but it is not clear that these support anything fancier than wildcards so a negative (reject if not semver) doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Yell at whoever's pushing non-compliant tags.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I have managed is to create an action which checks the tag format and add it to the start of all the workflows.  The workflow fails if the tag format is invalid.

Works but somewhat inefficient; would be nice if GitHub had server side hook that did this during tag pushes ;-).